# how to create a new bufferedreader for every file in a directory java

Tags: java

I have a bunch of files in a directory, I want to read all of them simultaneously.
In my code he will read all the files but one by one.

---

```
public void OptimiserListeDesTermes(String repertoireToFileTermes) throws IOException {

    File dir = new File(repertoireToFileTermes);

    if (dir.isDirectory()) {

        File[] list = dir.listFiles();
        String nameFich = "";
        if (list != null) {

            for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

                nameFich = list[i].getPath();

                FileReader filereader = new FileReader(ReadPath(nameFich));

                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(filereader);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public void OptimiserListeDesTermes(String repertoireToFileTermes) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(repertoireToFileTermes);
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] list = dir.listFiles();
        if (list != null) {
            Arrays.stream(list).filter(f -> f.isFile() && f.canRead()).parallel().forEach(file -> {
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    ...
                } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
                    // log the error
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Or like this?

```
public void OptimiserListeDesTermes(String repertoireToFileTermes) throws IOException {
    File dir = new File(repertoireToFileTermes);
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        File[] list = dir.listFiles();
        if (list != null) {
            int buffers = 0;
            BufferedReader[] readers = new BufferedReader[list.length];
            for (File file : list) {
                if (file.isFile() && file.canRead()){
                    readers[buffers++] = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                }

            }
            readers = Arrays.copyOf(readers, buffers);                

            // do something with readers
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you it did help so if i want to read all of them simultaneously, i will have to create an array of string that contains the first line of every file.?because now i need to compare the content of every file within each other.